# Folder navigation using keyboard in Coda

Tags: keyboard, development, coda

I'm trying to navigate on Coda using only the keyboard, but I can't seem to find the shortcuts. You can expand a folder by pressing the right arrow key, but I can't seem to mimic double clicking using the keyboard.

When you double click, you actually enter the context of that particular folder. It would also be good to know how to navigate to the parent folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> to navigate between folders.